# upload a file to a specific folder php

Tags: php

My purpose is  uploading a remote file create from my PC to specific folder, but I don't know whats wrong with my code below. It uploads the file with the name and the .jpg extension, but it is not moving the file to the specified folder.

```
if(isset($_POST["image"])){  

    define("SITE_NAME","project_name/"); //constant for project name
    define("SITE_PATH",$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/".SITE_NAME); //constant for project base directory
    define("IMAGES_URL",SITE_URL."images/"); //constant for image directory

    $upload_base_dir=IMAGES_URL;
    $upload_time_dir=date('Y')."/".date('m')."/".date('d')."/"; // setup directory name
    $upload_dir = $upload_base_dir.$upload_time_dir;

    if (!file_exists($upload_dir)) {
      mkdir($upload_dir, 0777, true);  //create directory if not exist
    }

    $input = $_POST["image"];
    $file = fopen(time()."image.jpg", 'wb');
    fwrite($file, $input);

    //$image_name=basename($_FILES['image']['name']);
    $image=time().'_'.$image_name;
    move_uploaded_file($file,$upload_dir.$image);

    fclose($file);

}
```

Any suggestions? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Problem is that you don't uploading image, you need to `move_uploaded_file()` function. Here is basic example http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php

Comment: Correct spelling, formatting, grammar and clarity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

move_uploaded_file($file,$upload_dir.$image) will only work for items within temp, that are accessable via $_FILES superglobal. If you are sending your file as a strieam within post, that wont work.

1) If file is a form upload make sure form is a multipart and access your file via $_FILES superglobal

```
move_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'], $yourDirectory.$yourFilename);
```

2) If you post the file as a stream via post (keep in mind this will only work for small files as large ones will exceed request limit). Save the file directly to it's destiantion using fopen or to move it after you created it use rename() - http://php.net/manual/en/function.rename.php

```
rename($currentFilePath, $newFilePath)
```

P.S. sending files as post streams is a very very bad idea.

Comment: i see,this why it was not working...so i cannot make dir wheil i am uploading the file and put there the file?my file is maximum 300kb anyway

Comment: are you uploading via regular form?

Comment: no i am not uploading it via form,this why i am stucked here.

Comment: post your form.

Comment: If it is a form upload and your form is set as <form enctype="multipart/form-data"  Then you would save it like this: move_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'], $yourDirectory.$yourFilename);

Comment: Ah ok, if it is not a form than you should use something like: rename("/tmp/tmp_file.img", "/home/user/login/docs/my_file.img"); more info here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.rename.php